# entity framework in a different project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have my entity framework in a different class library project. EF version:6.
I want to access the data model from another project (multiple projects).
So I have added the reference in the executing project.
Both projects have the same connection string in the .config file.

But when I run the project, i get the following error:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)"

Note: It was working good when I had the EF in the same project.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your exe project has the connection string in the config file and the database exists and accessible.

Comment: ok..I have everything you mentioned in place. The only thing I didn't have is the connection string name in Identity Model. I have changed that and now encountered with a new problem.. "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context."